Pass two properties to a DataGridCell style using converters
I want to create a DataGridCell which can be set as read only or editable (it also changes its appearance) depending on a property.
I created a style for the cell :
<Style x:Key="LockableTextCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <converter:LockableCellConverter2 x:Key="cellConverter" />
    </Style.Resources>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource cellConverter}, ConverterParameter=locked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource cellConverter}, ConverterParameter=text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource cellConverter}, ConverterParameter=locked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource cellConverter}, ConverterParameter=text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

The converters (proof of concept like, i wouldn't leave them like this)
 public class LockableCellConverter : IMultiValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         return (values[0].ToString(), (bool)values[1]);
     }

     public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
 }


 public class LockableCellConverter2 : IValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         string option = parameter.ToString();
         
         try
         {
             (string text, bool locked) = ((string, bool))value;

             if (option == "text")
                 return text;
             else if (option == "locked")
                 return locked;

             return null;
         }
         catch
         {

             if (option == "text")
                 return "";
             else if (option == "locked")
                 return false;

             return null;
         }
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }


And it is used like this in a DataGrid
  <DataGridTextColumn
      CellStyle="{StaticResource LockableTextCell}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource lockableCellConverter}">
              <Binding Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  Mode="TwoWay" />
              <Binding Path="IsLocked" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"  Mode="OneWay" />
          </MultiBinding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  </DataGridTextColumn>

The LockableCellConverter convert method gets called and returns what i expect, but the LockableCellConverter2 never gets called (Convert & ConvertBack). I just get a XAML Binding Failure saying: "Value '(test, True)' cannot be assigned to property TextBlock.Text (type String)."
Could someone tell me why the converter in the style doesn't get called?
I allready tried another approach, but that way i have to create two DataTemplates per Column and i need to use it on multiple columns, so a reuseable approach would be better.

You got an XAML binding failure because LockableCellConverter returns a tuple of string and bool. When you don't set CellTemplate property, it assumes TextBlock should be used. TextBlock's Text property's type is string. However LockableCellConverter return type is not string. So, you got Xaml Binding Failure. If you set LockableCellConverter2 as a converter of MultiBinding, it won't work because the converter type of MultiBinding is IMultiValueConverter, not IValueConverter.

If you want that kind of control, I suggest using a DataGridTemplateColumn.
